# Keeping the priority orders and extracting the values based on that in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
id,val1,val2,val3
1,Nan,2,3
2,1,Nan,Nan
3,7,5,np.Nan
```

Here the last column is val3 and this is the priority columns. If the priority columns contain the data, then I take that column data. If that column is Nan, then I would like to take the second priority data. In this case, it would be val2.

Currently, I am using `np.where` but this gets very pretty big once the number of columns increases. Is there any better approach?

my expected output would be this:

```
id,main_val
1,3
2,1
3,5
```

the value remains the same in the first row as the priority columns had values. Second, it takes the values from val1 as this was the only one. In the third, it takes the values from val2 columns as this gets the priority over val1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create index by `id` column, forward filling missing values and select last column by position by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df1 = df.set_index('id').ffill(axis=1).iloc[:, -1].rename('main_val').reset_index()
print (df1)
   id  main_val
0   1       3.0
1   2       1.0
2   3       5.0
```

If possible another columns and need select only priority columns use:

```
cols = ['val1','val2','val3']
df1 = df.set_index('id')[cols].ffill(axis=1).iloc[:, -1].rename('main_val').reset_index()
```

Comment: Thank you, this was great. I was going in wrong direction using `np.where` for this. Will accept the answer after 10 mins passed :)